# How to create SVN dump files for multiple revisions without repeating the command

Tags: java, svn, tortoisesvn

I am creating .dump files for a project hosted on SVN and want to create dumps for multiple revisions. Currently the command being used in the cmd prompt is:

`svnrdump dump https://some.org.com/svn/project -r 1234 --incremental > Project_rev1234.dump`

This command would create the dump file for r1234 for the project, but say I wanted to do revs 1234->1300 without typing the command out dozens of times. How would I achieve this? I am completely new to SVN and dump commands.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnrdump.html#svn.ref.svnrdump.sw.revision) says that -r might be a range
so you could try something like:

```sh
svnrdump dump https://some.org.com/svn/project -r 1234:1300 --incremental > Project_rev1234.dump
```